# Problema al pasar de un Fragmen a otro Fragment

Tags: android-fragment

tengo unas clases Fragment en las que he añadido unos botones para pasar de un Fragmen a otro Fragmen.

He liedo comentarios que para las **transiciones entre Fragment** se utilice `FragmentTransaction` y en lugar de `getFragmentManager` o `getSupportFragmentManager` que se utilice `getChildFragmentManager`

No sé si lo estoy haciendo bien, pero no me está funcionando, este es el código que no me funciona:

```
botonSF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SegundoF fragment = new SegundoF();
            FragmentTransaction ftSF = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ftSF.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            ftSF.addToBackStack(null);
            ftSF.commit();

        }
    });
```

En cambio, utilizando este otro código si puedo pasar de un Fragment a otro Fragment, no sé si en un futuro pueda dar algún problema al no utilizar FragmentTransaction

```
botonSF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(android.R.id.content, new SegundoF())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
        }
    });
```

La verdad no sé porque funciona, porque si os fijáis, en el primer código para reemplazar el fragment utilizo **R.id.frame_container** en cambio es el segundo código utilizo **android.R.id.content**;

en **activity_main.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

Cómo es que funciona este segundo código si en el activity_main.xml tengo puesto "@+id/frame_container” ?
Y porque no funciona el primer código?

Luego cuando muestro el contenido del segundo Fragment, se queda encima del menú, se superpone al TabLayout 
¿porque se muestra el Fragment encima del menú, como podría ponerlo debajo para que no tape el menú?

Este video de ejemplo muestro lo que he comento y el problema con el Fragment
https://youtu.be/PhJRtBpI0lM

Otro problema con el que me he encontrado en otra ocasión es que el fragment se muestra uno encima de otro, como podéis ver en este video de ejemplo.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqIoDqR6lSY

Es ente caso no se superpone al menú, pero se muestran los dos fragment, como puedo evitar que no se muestren los dos fragment.

Logcat del video que muestra el error

```
2018-12-08 19:00:31.037 19096-9071/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2018-12-08 19:00:32.800 18710-18723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-08 19:00:41.076 18710-18723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-08 19:00:47.663 18710-18723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-08 19:01:08.036 12055-12055/? E//system/bin/webview_zygote32: Failed to make and chown /acct/uid_99075: Permission denied
2018-12-08 19:01:08.036 12055-12055/? E/Zygote: createProcessGroup(99075, 0) failed: Permission denied
2018-12-08 19:01:08.078 12077-12077/? E/asset: setgid: Operation not permitted
2018-12-08 19:01:23.399 18710-18723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-08 19:01:57.239 18710-18723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-08 19:02:57.309 18710-18723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-08 19:03:33.258 11988-12007/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2018-12-08 19:03:33.258 11988-12007/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2018-12-08 19:03:33.950 11988-12007/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2018-12-08 19:03:33.951 11988-12007/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2018-12-08 19:03:34.564 11988-12007/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2018-12-08 19:03:34.565 11988-12007/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
2018-12-08 19:04:00.027 18710-18723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-08 19:04:21.144 19096-9071/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2018-12-08 19:04:23.304 11988-11988/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f070048     (com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu:id/frame_container) for fragment Esta_S_Ga{28445a #0 id=0x7f070048}
2018-12-08 19:04:23.304 11988-11988/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
2018-12-08 19:04:23.343 11988-11988/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu, PID: 11988
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070048 (com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu:id/frame_container) for fragment     Esta_S_Ga{28445a #0 id=0x7f070048}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1413)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2018-12-08 19:04:24.574 19096-11457/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7
2018-12-08 19:04:24.844 19096-19096/? E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
2018-12-08 19:04:24.878 19096-19096/? E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En el código donde utilizas **android.R.id.content**, si trabajas con FragmentTransaction por medio del método **beginTransaction()**.

Reemplaza

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(android.R.id.content, new SegundoF())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

Por

```java
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, new SegundoF())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

Comment: Hola @MVPFrans, no se si lo he entendido bien, en los dos codigo utilizo **beginTransaction()** y el código que pones que tengo que reemplazar es el mismo que digo que estoy utilizando, y el que funciona, y una de las cosas que pregunto es que si seria correcto utilizar ese codigo ya que aconsejan para las transiciones entre fragment utilizar el primer codigo.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el código, respecto a si es correcto o no, te adjunto un link donde muestra la diferencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740445/what-is-difference-between-getsupportfragmentmanager-and-getchildfragmentmanag, y practicamente indica que ambos devuelven un FragmentManager, getChildFragmentManager() administra fragmentos dentro del fragmento y getSupportFragmentManager administra fragmentos   asociados con la actividad de ese fragmento.

Comment: Aunque mi ingles es nulo y según la traducción y lo que dices tú dices, es que se puede utilizar el segundo método, pero porque se queda el segundo Fragment fuera del contenedor tapando el menú, esto también me ha pasado con alguna clase que extiende de AppCompatActivity, como se puede corregir eso para que se muestren donde se tiene que mostrar.

Comment: Y hay un problema, no se si por utilizar ese código, pero cuando muestro el Fragment no puedo utilizar la flecha atrás para volver a la actividad anterior, es porque `getFragmentManager` pertenecer a **Activity** y `getChildFragmentManage` rpertenecer a **Fragment** es que si eso es asi igual no se tendria que utilizar este metodo

Comment: Bueno como parece que MVPFrans ya no va a seguir, si hay alguien mas que quiera echarme una mano, a resolverlo se lo agradecería

Comment: @SoCu al instancear el ViewPagerAdapter pasas como parámetro getChildFragmentManager o getFragmentManager? Al dar clic al botón S_GA y S_VI reemplazarán el contenido del menu VerEsta? o cada uno debe mostrarse en distintas partes del contenido del menu VerEsta? en el primer video presentas un inconveniente, puedes mostrarnos el log por favor, saludos.

Comment: Ni el **getFragmentManager** ni **getChildFragmentManager** con **R.id.frame_container** funciona, el VerEsta muesta el Fragment Esta2, y el botón que tiene con S_GA muestra otro Fragment que se llama Esta_S_Ga, que reemplazar el contenido del Fragment Esta2, ahora mismo no te puedo pasar el Log, porque tengo desactivadas partes del menú, y que al pulsar en otro botón me está mostrando esa parte sin llamarla, muy raro, si antes no entendia nada, ahora menos, jeje, si consigo ponerlo en funcionamiento te pongo el Log.

Comment: Mira el código que da error https://youtu.be/iAewWJamG2k y este otro código no da error https://youtu.be/M6UHnnyBQhg pero es un desastre como muestra los fragment superpuestos y tapando el menú, incluso mostrando un Fragment pulso una parte que se ve de un menú que hay debajo y la imagen/fragment de ese menú se muestra debajo del que está en ese momento, y si pulso en otro menú que tiene un botón, la imagen sigue estando por encima de los menús. Arriba he puesto el Logcat del error.y el video como te voy mostrando los fragment y sus xml puedes ver el codigo que tiene.

Comment: El archivo Esta2.java es un fragment? Si es si, el id frame_container, deberias tenerlo en el layout de Esta2 y no en el Activity, si es posible sube tu codigo a un repositorio para hecharte una mano, saludos.

Comment: repositorio te refieres aun servidor como Mega ? si pongo el frame_container en Esta2 cuando pulso el boton se muestra otro fragmen diferente, eso es lo que me pasa con otro menu

Comment: GitHub, Drive, Mega...

Comment: Aqui esta el enlace https://goo.gl/1QVxyY te he puesto tambien un txt, te he subido tal y como esta en la carpeta del proyecto.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86816/discussion-between-mvpfrans-and-socu).